# What is wrong with this Random String Generator?

Tags: php, arrays, string, random, generator

I have edited some code that I found online to generate a random string in PHP which I am going to use as an ID.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ID Generator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="idgen.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php 

class randomPassword {

    function __construct( $passType='alphaNumeric', $length=64, $rangeLength=9 ) {
        $this->passType = $this->setPassType( $passType );
        $this->setLength( $length );
        $this->setRangeLength( $rangeLength );
    }

    function setRangeLength( $rangeLength ) {
        $this->rangeLength=$rangeLength;
    }

    // set the length of the password
    private function setLength( $length ) {
        $this->length=$length;
    }

    // set the type of password
    private function setPassType( $passType ) {
        return $passType.'Chars';
    }

    // return an array of numbers
    private function numericChars() {
        return range( 0, $this->rangeLength );
    }

    // return an array of lowercase chars
    private function lcAlphaChars() {
        return range( 'a', 'z' );
    }

    //return an array of uppercase chars
    private function ucAlphaChars() {
        return range( 'A', 'Z' );
    }

    // return an array of all alpha chars
    private function alphaChars() {
        return array_merge( $this->lcAlphaChars(), $this->ucAlphaChars() );
    }

    // return an array of alphanumeric chars
    private function alphaNumericChars() {
        return array_merge( $this->alphaChars(), $this->numericChars() );
    }

    // return array of lowercase characters and numbers
    private function lcAlphaNumericChars() {
        return array_merge( $this->lcAlphaChars(), $this->numericChars() );
    }

    // return array of uppercase characters and numbers
    private function ucAlphaNumericChars() {
        return array_merge( $this->ucAlphaChars(), $this->numericChars() );
    }

    // return a string of chars
    private function makeString() {
        // set the function to call based on the password type
        $funcName = $this->passType;
        return implode( $this->$funcName() );
    }

    // shuffle the chars and return $length of chars
    public function makePassword() {
        return substr( str_shuffle( $this->makeString() ), 1, $this->length );
    }

} // end class

?>

<h3>ID Generator</h3>
<h4>LC Alpha Numeric</h4>
<?php
    for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
    {
        try
        {
            $obj = new randomPassword( 'lcAlphaNumeric', 32, 9 );
            echo $obj->makePassword().'<br />';
        }
        catch( Exception $ex )
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is some sample output:

```
9hx2qwuvjbyn18tceosp75gkf30mrli4
tzqujok5xnr783wem6sv2afcgi9h1d0y
87bxc9vr6sewaoltkni24jdgh3z1fu05
j2shgmd4o6w09yx85avp1iflqubtk3nc
0r1q9engl43uv5poxfjd6zi8cha72ytk
```

If I try the same again but this time increasing the length to 64 (so to avoid collision) it only produces a string of length 36 (Its maximum as **the elements are *NOT* repeating**). How can I make it so that it can choose anything from the arrays?

Comment: `$obj = new randomPassword( 'lcAlphaNumeric', 32, 9 )` Did you change it here to 64?

Comment: Yes, as I said it stops at length 36 (26 letters and 10 numbers [0-9]) as it doesn't reuse the elements in the array.

Comment: Not possible with the way this is writen. It builds an array of usable chars and simply shuffles it. Since you're allowing only lower case alphanumeric chars, it is impossible to turn a 36 char array into 37+ chars. Not without fundamentally rewriting this routine.

Comment: You're generating a string by shuffing an array of all the possible values, so it'll generate 36 characters at most - as you say, that's as long as it gets. If you want to get a longer password, you'll need to re-write it - say by shuffling the array as many times as the desired length of the password and selecting the first character each time.

Comment: Could I not just select a random element each time?

Comment: @Mike - that would also work, yes.

Comment: @Mike - use `rand()` to select a random int between 0 and the array length. http://ca1.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `openssl` extension for that:

```
$secret = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length * 2));
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I get weird characters in the browser. I just want to allow alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Thank you. I will accept after the 5 minute limit. Do you know how I could have completed it my way though?

Comment: Thanks :) Basically you only need some "good" randomness, and transfer that to an ascii sequence of letters. While my idea will work well, you **need** that `length * 2` (!!)  to make it random enough..

Comment: So if I want a length of 64 I should use $length = 32 and in the function use $length * 2?

Comment: No, you need to pass 64, but you get 128 characters. That's because my random generator generates complete random values, not just those printable by ascii. This is better randomness, but it requires to display the string as hex, meaning two letters per byte.

Comment: If I only want 64 characters? What is wrong with only 64 characters? That already allows for 4011991914547630480065053387702443812690402487741812225955731622655455723258857248542161222254985216 permutations.

Comment: @Mike this way is more secure, but harder to maintain (for humans).. If you are searching for a more common way, try `pwgen`. It's a Linux command line tool. You can call it like `$password = system('pwgen -s 64 1');`

Comment: @Mike I have to leave office soon. If you want, we can discuss this later in chat

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48293/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-mike)